# Why 'self.self' compiles and run in swift?

Tags: swift, oop, instance-variables, self

Yesterday I reviewed a piece of code in Swift which included this line:

```
self.self.someProperty
```

Which surprised me, because the word **self** is reserved and used as a reference to the current instance.

At first I checked for that phenomenon in other languages, but all gave errors. Which wasn't a surprise - but still, why in swift does it compile and run?

Second I searched in the internet about this and haven't found anything relevant...

**Edit**
I reproduced that and from my checks:

```
self.someProperty//exactly the same as:
self.self.someProperty//or as:
self.self.self.self.self.someProperty
```

[Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)  gives some sort of explanation:

> *Every instance of a type has an implicit property called self, which is exactly equivalent to the instance itself*.

Which is good and partly helpful, but the way I see it it's still not enough

So I'm asking:

1. Why does it work?
2. Is there any useful logic behind this?

Comment: I see someone already answered the question, but [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID238) is some further info on the `self` property and some of its uses.

Comment: I've read it, thank you. I also added this link to the question ->  and it gives some sort of explanation. But it's not really answering _Why_ it's more like stating a fact, and not gives any use for _self.self_ I mean there is a reason why the same thing gives an error in other languages So I guess there should also be a reason why it works here and (more important) where should it be used.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Although that section claims to talk about a `self` implicit "property", none of the examples use it in a uniquely "property" manner -- all the examples are consistent with it being an implicit parameter of the method (like it is in Objective-C), because they all just use `self` directly without qualification. So it doesn't really explain why it exists as a property.

Answer (score 7):

It's because the `.self` property of an object is that object itself. So your second `self` changes nothing.

You could, in fact, extend this game indefinitely (or as long as your patience holds out):

```
let s = "Hello".self.self.self.self.self.self.self.self
// s is still simply "Hello"
```

Comment: I also found it just now - but what is the usage of it?
Or it's just because it's implicit property added to any instance?

Comment: Yes. Being overly selfish doesn't have any benefit.

Comment: @NikitaKurtin It is often useful when the object in question is a _class_ object; there are situations where adding `.self` to the name of a class, or to some property or variable that holds a class, is helpful to the compiler. Otherwise, it isn't something you would actually do.

Comment: @matt Can you give an example of: _situations where adding .self to the name of a class, or to some property or variable that holds a class, is helpful to the compiler_ ?

Comment: @matt From my experience sometimes small things can make big differences and I have a feeling that this might be the case.

Answer (score 5):

Yup, no matter how many .self's you have after a string, it's still just itself