# Extension Methods return value in Swift

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift 2. Being learning extension, which I found it is pretty cool feature compared with OC.

An example from apple developer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

```
extension Int {
    mutating func square() {
        self = self * self
    }
}
var someInt = 3
someInt.square()
// someInt is now 9
```

So I was thinking, is it possible to have extension to return value like this:

```
extension Int {
    func square() {
        return self * self
    }
}
var someInt = 3
someInt.square()
//ERROR: error: no '*' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '()'
```

My question is how to return a value within an extension?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26836477/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with any other function, you'd need to specify the return type.

```
extension Int {
    func squared() -> Int {
        return self * self
    }
}
let someInt = 3
let square = someInt.squared()
```