# What is the need for "self" in Swift when returning the number of lines

Tags: swift

To return the number of cells there are in the tableView

```
return self.myExample.count
```

returns the same amount of cells as

```
return myExample.count
```

I wanted to ask what is the reason of the `self`?
In the above code, `myExample` is a array which contains names and should be displayed on a tableView.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835013/what-is-self-used-for-in-swift

Comment: Okay! Thanks I didn't find that result when I searched.