# How to get property of tapped button mapped from array?

Tags: swift, events, uibutton

I am trying to print properties from an array containing properties of a class when tapping on that button, I have read some answers but none are working. apparently println() use to work but it seems to have been depreciated. Below is the code in question:

this is the buttons class

```
class Buttons{
   var nature = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
    var name: String
  

    init ( name: String) {
        self.name = name
       
    }
}
```

this is the array in the main class

```
var buttonsArray=[
    Buttons(name: "below")
            ,
    Buttons(name: "front")
           ,
    Buttons(name: "right")
           
    ]
```

mapping:

```
for val in buttonsArray{

            val.nature.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: 10, width: 20, height:20)
            val.nature.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * 0.12*bounds.size.width
            val.nature.clipsToBounds = true
            val.nature.backgroundColor = .blue
            sceneView.addSubview(val.nature)
        
        
            val.nature.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
            val.nature.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
            val.nature.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonOut), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
            val.nature.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonOut), for: UIControl.Event.touchDragExit)
        
        }
```

assigned func

```
@objc func profileButtonClicked(button: self){
print(button.name)
}
```

I get an error in the function thought but the point is to print the tapped button name.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function parameter like
`@objc func profileButtonClicked(button: Button){ print(button.name) }`

For reference, you can see
[1]: [What is "self" used for in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835013/what-is-self-used-for-in-swift)

You also mentioned you are getting error. It would be better if you share the error message.

Comment: I've already tried that it does not work and there is an error saying: Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: If you want to use your class from objective-c. Then you should extend at least NSObject in your Button class.

Comment: just tried what you suggested and I got this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff86e8d840)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting bad access. In that case I have two solutions for you, I tested both and worked well.

First one, you need to modify your profileButtonClicked() function like below

```
@objc func profileButtonClicked(_ button: Buttons){
    for x in buttonsArray {
        if x.nature == button {
            print(x.name)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Or I prefer this one,

Main class change would be,

```
 var buttonList = [ 
    ButtonTest(name: "below"),
    ButtonTest(name: "front"),
    ButtonTest(name: "right")]

 for button in buttonList {
       sceneView.addSubview(button)
 }
```

You can replace Button class with ButtonTest,

```
class ButtonTest: UIButton {
   var name: String
   init(name: String){
    self.name = name
    super.init(frame:.zero)

    self.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: 10, width: 100, height:40)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * 0.12 * 200
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.backgroundColor = .blue
    //self.setTitle(name, for: .normal)
    self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    //self.contentEdgeInsets  = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: -25.0)
    //view.addSubview(val.nature)
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
    //
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

@objc func profileButtonClicked(button: ButtonTest){
    print(button.name)
}
```

}